# Creating object literal with generic key fails to compile

Tags: typescript

I am trying to do the following

```
function createRecord<T extends string>(key: T) : Record<T, T> {
    return {[key]: key}; // Type '{ [x: string]: T; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<T, T>'

}
```

However is seems that the computed property is inferred as a string type by the typescript compiler rather than the string literal T, is it possible to implement the above function without any type assertions?

Comment: You’re going to need type assertions (see ms/TS#47703 for example) Also note that if `T` is a union your `Record` type is not going to be correct, if it matters.

Comment: Let me know if you want to see an answer with this info explained, or if I’m missing something about your question.

Comment: @jcalz Yes it seems it is not possible to do it without type assertions you can add it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948) noting that computed property keys are often widened to `string`, and that this is often not what people want.  Things work fine when your computed key is of a single string [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):

```
const a = "a";
const x = { [a]: "" } // {a: string}, okay
```

But as soon as you have a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) key

```
const ab = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b" // const ab: "a" | "b"
const y = { [ab]: "" } // { [x: string]: string},
```

or a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) key

```
// (parameter) k: K extends PropertyKey
const z = { [k]: "" } // { [x: string]: string},
```

the type gets widened to a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures).

That issue is still open, with no obvious resolution in sight.  Similar issues have been closed as design limitations; see [microsoft/TypeScript#47703](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47703) for a fairly recent one.

---

That means, for now, if you want to see the compiler treat objects with computed keys as a different type, you'll have to use something like a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to persuade it to do so.  My suggestion for your `createRecord()` would be

```
function createRecord<K extends string>(key: K) {
  return { [key]: key } as { [P in K]: Record<P, P> }[K]
}
```

This behaves similarly to `Record<K, K>`:

```
const aRec = createRecord("a"); // Record<"a", "a">
```

but you can see a difference when the type of `key` is a union:

```
const abRec = createRecord(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b")
// const abRec: Record<"a", "a"> | Record<"b", "b">
```

If you pass in either `"a"` or `"b"`, you want `abRec` to be either `{a: "a"}` or `{b: "b"}`.  If you left it as `Record<K, K>` where `K` is `"a" | "b"`, then you'd get the type `{a: "a" | "b"; b: "a" | "b"}`, which is not appropriate as it claims both keys are present.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-0CFQVap1BoCJotJBtTo9fpeobzb1gsYTIpRrlaeOBhzBhxmuaV2wjYMjUO0-I2tthIA)