# Why does TypeScript reject this generic function declaration using mapped types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types

Using TS 5.1.3:

```
$ npx tsc --version
Version 5.1.3
```

I have the following function:

```
const valueToObject = <K extends PropertyKey>(name: K) => 
  <T>(v: T): { [P in K]: T } => 
  ({ [name]: v });
```

It works like this:

```
valueToObject('id')('1234')
> { id: '1234' }
```

The 'forced' return type `{ [P in K]: T }` makes it work correctly:

```
const idToObject = valueToObject('id');

// Properly inferred as const idToObject: <T>(v: T) => {id: T}

idToObject('1234')
> { id: '1234' }
```

And it *does* work at run-time as expected, but TypeScript detects a type bug:

```
$ npx tsc --noEmit
... - error TS2322: Type '{ [x: string]: T; }' is not assignable to type '{ [P in K]: T; }'.

42 const valueToObject = <K extends PropertyKey>(name: K) => <T>(v: T): { [P in K]: T } => ({ [name]: v });
                                                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Removing the "forced" return type does indeed show that `name` is always inferred as `string`:

```
const valueToObject = <K extends PropertyKey>(name: K) => 
  <T>(v: T) => 
  ({ [name]: v });
const idToObject = valueToObject('id');
const idToObject: <T>(v: T) => {[p: string]: T}
```

It actually seems to be inferred as an index signature rather than mapped type:

```
const value = idToObject(123);
console.log(value.asd); // doesn't complain about .asd
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71418367/2887218) to a similar question and [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).  Does that fully address the question or am I missing something?

Comment: Ugh yeah that's exactly it. `const valueToObject = <K extends PropertyKey>(name: K) => <T>(v: T) => ({ [name]: v }) as { [P in K]: T };` seems to work well, at least — the `as` is definitely better than a ts-ignore.

Wanna post this as an answer? I'll upvote it and accept it.